# GCP Create Firewall Rule to Deny All Outside the U.S.?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

We see a lot of scans and attempts to hack our various external ingresses in GCP and the majority of these come from outside the U.S.  The neat thing is that we don't service anyone outside maybe 5 U.S. states and I'd like to know how to only allow ingress from IPs located inside the U.S. How can I create a firewall rule that does this in GCP is that even possible? Google searches asking this question yield nothing, not even anyone asking this question. Netflix and Hulu seem to have no problems doing this, can we do it too?

Comment: Depending on your architecture, you might need to use a geolocation service and implement that internally to your systems. Software like WordPress has plugins for this. Other frameworks do as well. Google Cloud Armor offers Geo-based access control, which works with Google load balancers. https://cloud.google.com/armor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing GCP has to prevent attacks like DDoS or from hacking is [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-concepts). Google Cloud Armor delivers defense at scale against infrastructure and application Distributed Denial of Service (DDoS) attacks, using Google’s global infrastructure and security systems. Cloud Armor works in conjunction with Global HTTP(S) LB and provides a layer of protection for your applications running on the backend servers. You cannot use it without a Global HTTP LB.

To limit traffic and protect HTTPS LB, you can configure Cloud Armor security policies that are made up of rules that allow or prohibit traffic from IP addresses or ranges defined in the rule. You can create Google [Cloud Armor security policies](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies) with IP deny lists and allow lists that restrict unauthorized access to HTTP(S) Load Balancer from the internet. It’s worth mentioning that in GCP, [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) are specified in VPC level not coupled with HTTPS Load balancer. Additionally, you could get a little more information about GCP [Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf) for DDoS Protection and Mitigation on Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: We aren't seeing any DDoS attempts and these are kubernetes hosted apps which are all behind an ingress, not sure if Cloud Armor applies to those. What we are seeing is attempts at finding php exploits (we don't have any php apps running here) and scans for php files. We also see a lot of attempts at brute force attacks on pw's on our external sftp servers that various partners need access to. I'm hoping to resolve those with fail2ban. It'd be nice to just be able to hide everything external from anyone outside the U.S. since this is a site solely related to U.S. services.

Comment: I understand you are looking for a intrusion-detection and/or intrusion-prevention techniques to detect and/or prevent intrusions into the network.GCP does not offer IDS solutions as a product. You can use your own IDS systems as applications and we don't think there will be an issue with using that in GCP. You can search for related IDS tools or services N-IDS online.

Comment: However, Google Cloud Armor security policies are available only for backend services behind an external HTTP(S) load balancer, also  works fine with [GKE ingress with Global HTTP(S)LB](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress). You may also look into [GCP Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf) on Google Cloud Platform[2], this is not a direct IDS feature but has useful information about GCP security.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this is will answer you question or not, but there is a way to combine multiple GCP services like [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor), [Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore) and [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) you can dynamically configure a security policy that can serve your purpose, to add a functionality similar to fail2ban to a cloud environment.

I setup a tutorial for this and you can find it here [hodo.dev/posts/post-39-gcp-fail2ban-cloud-armor](https://hodo.dev/posts/post-39-gcp-fail2ban-cloud-armor/)